# Can css class have class in it self and how would it be done?

Tags: css, subclass

My friend and I have had argument about CSS specifity and he was bringing up a class inside of a class:

```
.class{ 
    .subclass{    
    }
}
```

I have tried testing this in css but attributes from `.subclass` are not being applied.

**My concern is are sub-classes done like this in css?**

Comment: that is a structure typical for CSS preprocessors like LESS or SCSS . Then it will be transformed in classic CSS like ` .class .subclass { } `

Comment: It also depends. If you want to apply these styles to an element that has both classes `class` and `subclass` then you will need to write `.class.subclass` for a selector, without a space.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in css, but you can do this in less (http://lesscss.org/) or sass(http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't accept nesting classes but SASS and LESS do.

- [Nesting in Sass and Less](http://markdotto.com/2015/07/20/css-nesting/)